# Decimal.MinValue & Decimal.MaxValue: why static readonly and not const modifiers?

Tags: types, static, constants, readonly, numeric

In C#, **MinValue** field is defined for numeric types with:

① **static readonly** modifiers for decimal type [(Link to MSDN Libray for .NET 4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static readonly decimal MinValue
```

② **const** modifier for all other numeric types:

```
//Integral signed numeric types
public const sbyte MinValue
public const short MinValue
public const int MinValue
public const long MinValue

//Integral unsigned numeric types
public const byte MinValue
public const ushort MinValue
public const uint MinValue
public const ulong MinValue

//Real numeric types
public const float MinValue
public const double MinValue
```

Why **const** modifier is not used to define Decimal.MinValue field ?

*Remarks*:

① Same question applies to numeric types **MaxValue** field.

② VB, C++ and F# also use different modifiers for decimal type so this question is not specific to C# language.

Comment: `Decimal` is not as primitive as the other types.

Comment: Note that (no matter what tricks were needed to make that possible in the source code), the `MinValue` field of the `Decimal` struct **is** a `const`, and acts like one. If you use Visual Studio and use "Go To Definition" (F12) on `decimal`, you will see "metadata" (C# code generated from the actual assembly via reflection) that shows `[DecimalConstant(0, 128, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295)] public const decimal MinValue = -79228162514264337593543950335m;`. So `MinValue` acts as a const. You can declare other `const` values from it, use it as default value for optional parameters, etc.

Comment: @MarkHurd While that is correct in .NET, it is important here that in the C# Specification, the type `decimal` is a **predefined type** in the language, it is a so-called simple type in C#, see [4.1 Value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691140.aspx) and [4.1.4 Simple types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144.aspx) (here I link an old version of the spec, but it is the same in the newest version). And C# allows `const` fields for all these "simple types", including `decimal`. Now when mscorlib contains source code of a "predefined type", some tricks may be needed.

Comment: So really, the question is no longer relevant, as in the actual code it is a `const` and not a `static readonly` as the documentation states. But, the rabbit hole is still pretty deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes decimal `MinValue` field as being `static readonly`, C# compiler treats it as `const`.

If `MinValue` field was readonly, following code would not compile, but it actually *does compile*.

`const decimal test = decimal.MinValue - decimal.MinValue;`

*Remarks*:

① Same answer applies to decimal type `MaxValue` field.

② For further details, Jon Skeet's gives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502671/2350579) an insight on how constant field implementation at IL level differs between:

- Primitive numeric types (integrals, float and double) and
- The non primitive numeric decimal type.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. I did some research, and the MS documentation on `Decimal` Min/Max fields explicitly says (note the wording is the same for both; shown in brackets for clarity):

> The value of this constant is [negative] 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.

The following code compiles with no problem:

```
public const decimal MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335M;
```

#### - Edit -

Note: here is the assignment of the field from the source for .NET 4.5 (downloaded PDB source from MS), the decimal constructor that is called by this code. Note that it is declaring a const value. It appears, at least for 4.5, that the documentation is *wrong*. (This would not be the first time MS documentation is incorrect).  It also appears that the source code won't compile, as pointed out in a comment by @Daniel.

```
public const Decimal MinValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, true, (byte) 0);
public const Decimal MaxValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, false, (byte) 0);

public Decimal(int lo, int mid, int hi, bool isNegative, byte scale)
{
  if ((int) scale > 28)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("scale", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_DecimalScale"));
  this.lo = lo;
  this.mid = mid;
  this.hi = hi;
  this.flags = (int) scale << 16;
  if (!isNegative)
    return;
  this.flags |= int.MinValue;
}
```

Also note: in the 2.0 framework, decimal is declared outright:

`public const Decimal MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335m;`

So, inconsistency and incorrect documentation is the conclusion I have reached. I will leave it to others to look at the other framework versions for a pattern.

Comment: Why there is const instead readonly, is it problem of decompiler? This code will not compiled with const keyword

Comment: Good point - this must be version-specific. 2.0 framework explicitly says `public const Decimal MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335m;`

Comment: It's impossible to use this in code in .net `public const Decimal MaxValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, false, (byte) 0);` Because constant initializer must be compile-time constant but not invocation of constructor. Is it clear?

Comment: Try to compile similar code, it doesn't matter struct or class in this case.

Comment: Maybe the MS source is incorrect? This wasn't a decompilation, it was downloaded from MS source server.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. It's strange with strange comment `This field is constant and read-only.` for MinValue and MaxValue. I've thought it's different things:)

Comment: I think the source was doctored. Wonder how many other doctored source files there are?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that these `Decimal` values *are* seen as constants from the languages' point of view (but not the CLR), as Jon Skeet mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502671/256431) to rmayer06's related question.

(I thought the reason for using `ReadOnly` instead of `Const` was so that the constructor was not called on every use of a `Const`, except that is :-( )

If you compile: `x == Decimal.MaxValue` in C# or VB.NET, the constant is constructed as if it was really a `Const`.

In VB.NET this is *not* true for `Decimal.One`, `Decimal.Zero` or `Decimal.MinusOne`, but these *are* treated as constants in C#. (BTW `String.Empty` is not seen as a constant in either language.)

So I believe these are baked into to languages as constants (sometimes, in VB's case).

In VB's case it *does* seem to prefer to load the `ReadOnly` values, except for `MaxValue`, and `Minvalue`. (That is `Const y1 As Decimal = Decimal.One` is effectively aliased by VB, but truly treated as a constant in C#.)

BTW `Date.MaxValue` is also `ReadOnly`, but it is *not* seen as a constant by VB.NET (even though it does have `Date` literals).

UPDATE: I haven't checked what the current results are for the most recent VB.NET or C# but the reference source does not treat any of `Decimal.One`, `Decimal.Zero`, `Decimal.MinusOne`, `Decimal.MaxValue` or `Decimal.MinValue` specially; they're all just [`public const`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,3442a6ae15487ddf).

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought it was for readability of the source code

```
public const Decimal MaxValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, false, (byte) 0);
```

seems more readable than the magic number:

```
public const Decimal MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335m
```

Comment: I don't know about more readable, but certainly it is more clear on where the number materialized from.